# Parent Pick Up in Google Sheets - Concatenation, but need a formula that removes empty cells and titles

Tags: concatenation, google-sheets-formula

I'm a school principal. We are using a QR code system for touchless parent pick up.  I have concatenated info into a single cell.  However, not every family has 5 children and I have many empty cells that need to be removed.  This is the formula I used to get the field heading and data concatenated:  =CONCATENATE(D$1,"  ",D2,char(10),E$1,"  ",E2,char(10),F$1,"  ",F2,char(10),G$1,"  ",G2,char(10),H$1,"  ",H2,char(10),I$1,"  ",I2,char(10),J$1,"  ",J2,char(10),K$1,"  ",K2,char(10),L$1,"  ",L2,char(10),M$1,"  ",M2).  How would I change the formula to remove the field title for all empty cells??????

I'm not a programmer. I've gotten this far and need assistance.  Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Tip: Sharing a spreadsheet with a sample of (fake) data along with the desired output will always help people understand better your situation and what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on getting this far!

Now use the TEXTJOIN formula `=TEXTJOIN( delimiter, TRUE, range to join )`

The delimiter is the thing between every cell. The TRUE (or the number 1) tells it to ignore empty cells (use FALSE to turn this off). The range has all the cells you want to join

Good luck :)